# How can I model a Diode in a Bond Graph?

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to analyze the following circuit and turn it into a bond graph so I can derive the state space equations from it. I'm getting stuck figuring out how to convert the diodes for the rectifier into bond graph elements.

Ignore the values for the circuit elements, the circuit drawing software I used automatically applies them and won't let me turn them off.

[image]

This is what I've gotten converted from the circuit into the bond graph so far. I feel like I've messed up a little somewhere, but I'm unsure exactly where as well. I'm hoping that figuring out how to convert diodes will help me to figure out how to fix that. I just realized I mislabeled the voltage source as SF instead of SE.

[image]

Comment: (Just so you know, assuming you're using CircuitLab (looks like it), you can turn the values off by just setting them to empty values.)

Comment: Ah thanks, never knew that.

Comment: Searching the internet for "bond graph diode" yields several papers .... are those not useful? Like one of the [first hits](http://www.msc-les.org/proceedings/imaaca/2011/IMAACA2011_273.pdf)

Comment: @Huisman, I did come across that paper (and I can use it's rectifier model to assist with my bond graph). However, I asked the question because I don't fully understand the contents of that paper, and was hoping to get a simpler explanation of how to relate diodes to bond graphs, so that I'm not using material blindly.